# HTML5 video not loading in Safari on iOS 8.2

Tags: wordpress, video, safari, ios

Here's my code right now:

```
<div class="home-text-wrapper">

<?php 
global $smof_data;

if($smof_data['rnr_home_type']=="Callout Text") { ?>

<div class="container homevideo" overflow-scroll="true">
    <video id="video" autoplay loop="" preload="none" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" muted controls poster="http://puppod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/PosterImage.png">
        <source src="http://puppod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/PPiOS.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://puppod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/PPAndroid.mp4">
        <source src="http://puppod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/PupPod.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://puppod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/PupPod.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Video not found.
    </video>
</div>

<?php }
</div>
```

This is a WordPress installation. The PHP activates the video section when the "Callout Text" option is chosen in the theme settings.

The video works in every other browser, including Safari on iOS prior to the most recent 8.2 update. Currently, on iOS, Safari shows my loading GIF where the video should be and cuts off most of the website.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try clearing your cache, history, etc. in Safari on your mobile device and check again. If the problem persists, can you post the url so we can take a look?

Comment: I am seeing some odd behavior in 8.2 where the screen is not updating. Try rotating your iPad and see if it works. Also I am confused about what you mean about cutting off the website-do you think this is part of the issue or just bad CSS?. You may also like to go to JSfiddle.com and create a sample page that others can look at

Comment: Link to site: www.puppod.com

Comment: Cutting off the site i.e. the loading animation is not going away like it should and instead is displaying on the top 5/6 of the page.